# Optimising urinal use

Tags: physical

When you visit a urinal (so one for the gents), you’ll find that where urinals are arranged in groups of 3, the middle urinal and floor are typically cleaner than those to either side. This stems from the desire of users to avoid standing next to someone while using the urinal. Is there any evidence to indicate that the level of urinal preference can be reduced through either the use of modesty screens (in high-traffic urinals) or through arranging urinals in pairs (where space permits)?

Comment: Do we really need more bathroom questions on here? They were cute the first dozen times. Not so much anymore.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bathrooms.

Comment: @DA01 Glad you feel that way. Do remember not everyone has been on here since day dot, nor that every 'bathroom question' is intended as a joke.

Comment: If this is a genuine question and you're involved in some kind of urinal design business, you may be interested in http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=121310977

Comment: Strange that this has been put on hold as physical design questions are also part of UX and asked here on a reasonably regular basis. There doesn't appear to be anything in the help centre suggesting that physical design is out of scope. Thanks to those who have answered, disappointed that the prudishness of admins shuts down questions like this.

Comment: Okay, HAD to mention Male bathroom etiquette: www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzO1mCAVyMw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some [evidence](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/06/17/nyregion/answers-to-questions-about-new-york.html?_r=0) that gamification has been used to improve human behavior during urinal use, as shown by the [increasing use of flies and other "targets"](http://www.americanscientist.org/science/pub/theres-a-fly-in-my-urinal).

Perhaps including a gamification element *just for the underused urinals* can increase use?

Comment: Indeed! Apparently the Victorians had an image of a bee in the glaze much as these chaps have a fly. This was, I'm told, a Victorian joke, 'apis' being Latin for bee. (I feel I should apologise for the British at this point). Thanks - I think gamification is an important point to make!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer can come across as sarcastic, but hear me out.

**I think the cleanliness of floors around the middle urinal *is* the proof you seek.**

The walls on either side *are* the "privacy screens" you speak of. Nobody will be next to you there, and it's obvious that people prefer those, judging by the evidence you mentioned yourself!

Comment: Not at all - glad to see someone willing to engage with a serious question. Still interested to know of any research done into this area.